# Python: Accessing local variables in a function in script A from script B using inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, inheritance

I have a local variable within a function in class A. I initialize the class and declare the variables. I create a new function that returns the variable. In script 2 Class B, I import class A and create a new var that references the function in class A. When I run it it return None. Here is the code:

Script A: Class A

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.username = None        
        self.password = None
            
    def getUserName(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_secret(self):
    secret_name = ""
    
    self.username = None
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

      get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            creds = json.loads(secret)
            self.username = creds['username'] #Trying to return this value
        else:
           something
```

Script B: Class B

```
from Script_A import  A

   credentials = A()
   username = credentials.getUserName()
   print (username)
```

Script B when run returns None. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Can't see what I am doing wrong.

Correct code:

```
class A:
def __init__(self):

    self.username = None        
    self.password = None

def getUserName(self):
    self.get_secret()
    return self.username

def get_secret(self):
secret_name = ""
```

Comment: Where is class B? I also see no inheritance. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Looks like username gets set to None in A’s constructor and get_secret() is never called, so None is the expected value for B to see returned from getUserName()

Comment: In script B (which does not define any class) you create an object of class `A`. The `username` attribute of this object is `None`, so this is what is returned by the `getUserName()` method.

Comment: Yes I had totally forgotten to call the function wow. Thanks @JeremyFriesner

Comment: import boto3 ?? what is it ?

Comment: boto3 is an aws python sdk https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/